rsync a selection of directories to destination and delete anything else there
I have read the rsync docs and looked through threads here but cannot find a simple match for my requirement.
I wish to copy a number of directories/files from source to a destination directory.  I want the incremental copying, but I want anything else removed from the destination.  So in the destination we end up with an exact backup of the sources specified, and nothing else.
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p source/{A,B,C,D}
touch source/{A,B,C,D}/file
mkdir -p /tmp/dest/{A,B,E,F}
touch /tmp/dest/{A,B,E,F}/file
cd source
rsync -av --delete A B /tmp/dest/

I want /tmp/dest to end up with nothing but A and B, so E and F should get deleted --- but they do not.  Note that I do not wish to copy C and D from the source.  Note that I do not know what else might or might not be at the destination (nor at the source).
This seems like a common enough requirement for backing up some selective stuff and having the destination contain nothing but what was requested.  Anybody have the exact command for this, please?

You should be syncing source with dest while using inclusion and exclusion filters to specify exactly what you want.
When you sync A and B from within source to dest, you essentially sync source/A with dest/A and source/B with dest/B. The utility has no knowledge of any other directories under source or dest or how they should be handled.
Instead:
rsync -av --delete --delete-excluded \
    --include='A/***' \
    --include='B/***' \
    --exclude='*' \
    source/ /tmp/dest/

This asks rsync to make source and dest identical within the constraints given by the various filters. The / at the end of source/ is essential (without it, you'd get /tmp/dest/source as a directory), while the / at the end of the destination path is to ensure it's actually a directory.  The filters are applied to each name under source in a "first match wins" manner.  The two inclusion filters will match the A and B subdirectories and all of their contents (recursively).  The exclusion filter will match anything else.
We run with --delete and --delete-excluded which will both delete files that should not exist under dest on the destination (e.g., E and F or any deleted file under A or B), and it will delete anything matching an exclusion filter (e.g., C and D if they existed under dest).

From a comment about filter expressions:
In an inclusion or exclusion filter, * matches any name in a directory, ** matches any name in a directory or below it, and *** matches any name in a directory or below it but also the directory itself, i.e, A/*** and B/*** matches A and B, not just their contents.  If we were to use A/** and B/**, these directories would never be synced as the pattern A/** does not match A and B/** does not match B.
This is described in the rsync(1) manual.

Totally respect your answer!  But I find the required syntax a bit "tricky" (was hoping for something simpler), I will have to generate these lines in program code (not script) dynamically and from an unknown number of user-specified directories.  Will have to be careful to get that right.  Could you explain the *** you have used, please?

@JonBrave The * matches any name in a directory, ** matches any name in a directory or below it, and *** matches any name in a directory or below it but also the directory itself, i.e A and B, not just their contents.  If we were to use A/** and B/** then these directories would never be synced as the directory A does not match A/**.

@JonBrave If you have a list of directory names, generating the necessary inclusion filters seems like a fairly straightforward matter of concatenating each directory name with some static strings.

Thank you, I now found that *** documented in the rsync man page.  I will leave this question open for 24 hours in the hope of any other comments/"simpler" solutions, but when I don't get any I will mark yours as solution :)  Thanks.

"@JonBrave If you have a list of directory names," User will enter a string of desired directories to my program as a bash file expansion, e.g. {A,B,...}.  Would have been great for passing on command line for sources, syntax not accepted by rsync filter rules, so I will have to do some parsing or expansion work.... :(

@JonBrave If the user passes the names as arguments to a bash script, then just  inc=(); for arg do inc+=( --include="$arg/***" ); done.  Then rsync ... "${inc[@]}" --exclude='*' source/ dest/.
